# How do i display stored colors from my database?

Tags: php

I have a script that successfully stores the hex color code in my database when the user selects a color. How do i display this color that is being stored in my database on my page `color.php` instead of it displaying the hex color code of that picture stored in the database?

color.php

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","car");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM general";

$records=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered datatable">

<tbody>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general WHERE sex ='male' ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
 <tr>
         <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $row['general_id'];?>]" value="1" ></center> </td>

         <td><input  type="" name="f_name[]" value="<?php echo $row['f_name'];?>"></label></td>
         <td><input style="width: 100px" type="" name=" color[]" value="<?php echo $row['color'];?>"></label></td>
         <td><input type="" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row['options'];?>"></label></td>
         <td><input style="width: 100px" type="" name="comment[]" value="<?php echo $row['comment'];?>"></label></td>

 </tr>
<?php } //end of while loop?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In what format do you want to display it? As the pages text color? The background color of the page?

Comment: Echo relevant HTML and use CSS coloring (i.e. `color`, `background-color`, `border-color` or other) with fetched hex value. Note that hex values should begin with `#` character, are you storing it?

Comment: Sidenote: Be careful with the word `GENERAL` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#ftn.idm140726957039472 - *"added in 5.5.3 (reserved); became nonreserved in 5.5.8"* - Check for errors on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the cell of the color the background-color of your color inline like this:

```
 <tr>
         <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $row['general_id'];?>]" value="1" ></center> </td>

         <td><input  type="" name="f_name[]" value="<?php echo $row['f_name'];?>"></label></td>
         <td style="background-color:<?php echo $row['color'];?>;"><input style="width: 100px" type="" name=" color[]" value="<?php echo $row['color'];?>"></label></td>
         <td><input type="" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row['options'];?>"></label></td>
         <td><input style="width: 100px" type="" name="comment[]" value="<?php echo $row['comment'];?>"></label></td>

 </tr>
```

You could also give your text the color of the hex color you stored in the database or even the entire row, it's all up to you.

Comment: Worth mentioning the redundant `</label>` tags